# Input 0 of layer sequential is incompatible with the layer: expected axis -1 of input shape to have value 128 but received input with shape [32, 1]

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning, classification

Someone please elaborate this error and tell me that how to resolve it , i am supplying 128 expected input but it still giving me error what is this ?

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

Categories = ["SubCLassesOFShahiQila\Deewane aam", "SubCLassesOFShahiQila\Lahore Fort Museum",
              "SubCLassesOFShahiQila\Moti masjid", "SubCLassesOFShahiQila\Sheesh Mahal"]
sift = cv2.xfeatures2d.SIFT_create()


def prepare(filepath):
    IMG_SIZE = (124,124)
    img_array = cv2.imread(filepath, cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
    new_array = cv2.resize(img_array, IMG_SIZE)
    keyImage, desImage = sift.detectAndCompute(new_array, None)
    feat = np.sum(desImage, axis=0)
    return feat

model = tf.keras.models.load_model("mlp_model.h5")

prediction = model.predict([prepare('E:\Python Telusko\OpenCv\download.jpg')])
print(prediction)
print(Categories[int(prediction[0][0])])
```

Comment: Could you print a summary of the model and provide it here?

Comment: _________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
================================================================
dense (Dense)                (None, 32)                4128      
_________________________________________________________________
dense_1 (Dense)              (None, 4)                 132       
================================= =============================, So this 32 is the number of hidden neurons here why it is expecting it as input because i trained a model with 128 dimesnional input